# StartupTask.cpp build fail due to external dependencies

Tags: c++, visual-studio, raspberry-pi, windowsiot, windows-iot-core-10

I am trying to build a Windows IOT application for my Raspberry Pi using Visual Studio Community 2015. Here is the project template code.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "StartupTask.h"

using namespace BackgroundApplication1;
using namespace Platform;
using namespace Windows::ApplicationModel::Background;

// The Background Application template is documented at     http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=533884&clcid=0x409

void StartupTask::Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance^ taskInstance)
{

// TODO: Insert code to perform background work
//
// If you start any asynchronous methods here, prevent the task
// from closing prematurely by using BackgroundTaskDeferral as
// described in http://aka.ms/backgroundtaskdeferral
//
}
```

Although, every time I try to build this project I get a list of errors which come from external dependencies header files arm_neon.h, atomic.h, chrono.h, cstdint.h, and ratio .h. 
[image: List of errors]

I know I shouldn't have to touch these files since they were already included in the template yet I am not sure how to get rid of these erros. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the following package is installed,
[image]

And the Windows SDK too, which should be included in the above package.